# Can a Google Analytics goal fire only the first time a user does something?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, event-tracking, analytics-events

I have an app where users can create new projects.I would like to create a Google Analytics goal for when a user creates a project for the *first* time.

I currently have an event set up on the site each time the user creates a project, and a goal attached to that event.

The problem is that the goal is being recorded multiple times if the user creates multiple projects.

(I believe that the goal is only recorded once per session, but my users may create multiple projects across multiple sessions.)

Is there any way in GA I can restrict the goal so it is only recorded once per user?

If necessary I can restrict the event in client-side code, but it would be nice if I could do it in GA.